# CMake: ignore configure step if files didn't change

Tags: c++, cmake

It's widely documented on how to build llvm and clang to use them as standalone tools, on windows, and I'm creating a script to run this on CI.
The bat script calls cmake for the configuration step, but the configuration step takes more than 5 minutes to run and the build takes other ~40 minutes.

on linux, when running the cmake configuration step, it goes quite fast and does not produces artifacts again - improving compile times.

My configure step is as follows:

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" ^
        -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=Off ^
        -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=Off ^
        -DLLVM_ENABLE_DIA_SDK=1 ^
        -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" ^
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ^
        -DLLVM_ENABLE_LIBCXX=OFF ^
        -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_C_DYLIB=ON ^
        -DLLVM_POLLY_LINK_INTO_TOOLS=ON ^
        -DLLVM_BUILD_EXTERNAL_COMPILER_RT=ON ^
        -DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=ON ^
        -DLLVM_ENABLE_EH=ON ^
        -DLLVM_ENABLE_FFI=OFF ^
        -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON ^
        -DLLVM_INCLUDE_DOCS=OFF ^
        -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF ^
        -DLLVM_INSTALL_UTILS=ON ^
        -DLLVM_ENABLE_Z3_SOLVER=OFF ^
        -DLLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN=ON ^
        -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=all ^
        -DLLDB_USE_SYSTEM_DEBUGSERVER=ON ^
        -DLLDB_ENABLE_PYTHON=OFF ^
        -DLLDB_ENABLE_LUA=OFF ^
        -DLLDB_ENABLE_LZMA=ON ^
        -DLLDB_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF ^
        -DLIBOMP_INSTALL_ALIASES=OFF ^
        -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra;mlir;polly" ^
        -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="compiler-rt" ^
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%INSTALL_FOLDER%\llvm ^
        -Thost=x64 ^
        -B %BUILD_FOLDER%\llvm ^
        -S %SOURCE_FOLDER%\llvm-project-llvmorg-12.0.1\llvm
```

is there anything I can pass to cmake to check if the configuration already happened prior to reconfiguring it? a --only-if-not-configured or something.

Comment: Not that I’m aware of. Usually when in this situation I bypass cmake myself, instead just calling the build system directly (eg ninja, make). So maybe you can just add a flag to your script for that?

Comment: that will ignore subtle changes on the cmake configuration. if I need to touch the parameters that should reconfigure because the values changed. if I add my own test (checking if a folder exists, for instance), this will not work.

Comment: I see. Hope someone has a good answer.

Comment: Just build the project. If some file, which affects configuration, has been changed, then CMake **automatically** reconfigures the project before building it. (There are some changes, which couдd affect configuration in **non-detectable** manner: replacing the compiler's executable, adding or removing the library in the system, etc. In that case you need to rerun configuration manually.)

Comment: You have `LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD` set twice. First to just X86 and the second time to "all", which wins. You should really sort your list of `-D` flags to avoid such errors.